# How to make a DIV float on top of another DIV without pushing down the CSS Underneath

Tags: css, html

Please take a look at the following example:

http://jsfiddle.net/MVfVD/

I want the "overlayedFrameFooter" div to be onTOP of the frame, in a way where it doesn't add any height to the surrounding items.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[***Live Demo***](http://jsfiddle.net/MVfVD/4/)

- I added `position:relative` to `#frame`.
- I added `width:100%; text-align:center` to `#overlayedFrameFooter`.
- I changed `position:relative` to `position:absolute` on `#overlayedFrameFooter`.

[See here](http://css-tricks.com/absolute-positioning-inside-relative-positioning/) for an explanation of why this works.

Comment: Cool thanks! That plus adding a relative around the surrounding div in my app did the trick. thank you

Comment: I missed something minor out - to make this work in IE7, you have to add `left: 0` to `#overlayedFrameFooter`.