# overlapping divs on the right edge of the page

Tags: html, css, gwt, uibinder

I am having troubles for positioning a span with the watermark text on top of an input. The code using GWT+uibinder looks like that:

http://jsfiddle.net/camposcarlos/dMzL4/

and transformed into html looks like that:

http://jsfiddle.net/ajMWd/

instead of having the span overlapped on top of the input field by floating it to the left:

```
|----------------------------------|
|                |------------||--||
|                |passwd      ||Go||
|                |------------||--||
|                                  |
|----------------------------------|
```

I get it after the input

```
|----------------------------------|
|          |------------|      |--||
|          |            |passwd|Go||
|          |------------|      |--||
|                                  |
|----------------------------------|
```

or in the next line if I try to position the span relative to the width of the input

```
|----------------------------------|
|                |------------||--||
|                |            ||Go||
|                |------------||--||
|                 passwd           |
|----------------------------------|
```

Any ideas on how to solve it?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have been able to solve it using a nice solution from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4800035/how-to-make-a-div-float-on-top-of-another-div-without-pushing-down-the-css-under). 
The trick was to tag the container with a relative position style and the passwordbox and its span with absolute tags. It works with no need of specifying any position! (although I haven't tried with IE yet)
http://jsfiddle.net/ajMWd/4/

Answer (score 0):

If your problem is now that you want to display default text in a password box, but the password default text is unreadable, you will need to change your password input to be a normal text input before the user enters data.

Than, in your JavaScript, you can use the focus event to change it back to being a password-type input.

Try something like this:

```
<head>
   <script type="text/javascript">
      function changeToPassword() {
         document.getElementById("passwordSpan")
            .innerHTML = "<input id=\"password\" name=\"password\" type=\"password\"/>";
         document.getElementById("passwd").focus();
      }
   </script>
</head>
<body>
   <form>
      <span id="passwordSpan">
         <input onfocus="return changeToPassword()" id="passwd" name="passwd" type="text" value="Type Password" />
      </span>
   </form>
</body>
```

Comment: sure, the watermark logic is missing in the code provided. I have the logic for making it disapear once it gets focus, but I didn't put it to focus in the problem I have positioning the watermark text. Still I don't know how to position it correctly :(

Comment: Oh! I didn't realize that.
I think user1289347 had a valid approach if you can use absolute position. If you can't, you might want to try to make use of the more simple default value: <INPUT type="text" SIZE="10" MAXLENGTH="30" VALUE="Your Text">, and just use your JavaScript to control the watermarked font.

Comment: Hi theJollySin, that worked with the input for the login, however with the password input I cannot use this approach since the text appears masked.

Comment: I think I cannot use this approach in GWT (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10167116/watermark-on-password-text-input-using-gwt )